# condition in returning number of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `friends` below.

```
-----------------------------
| id | user_id | friends_id |
-----------------------------
| 1  |    1    |     2      |
-----------------------------
| 2  |    1    |     3      |
-----------------------------
| 3  |    1    |     4      |
-----------------------------
| 4  |    2    |     1      |
-----------------------------
| 5  |    3    |     5      |
-----------------------------
| 6  |    4    |     5      |
-----------------------------
```

and `SQL` query:

```
select user_id, friends_id from friends where user_id = 1
```

Above query gives me below result.

```
------------------------
| user_id | friends_id |
------------------------
|    1    |     2      |
------------------------
|    1    |     3      |
------------------------
|    1    |     4      |
------------------------
```

I want to get resul like this:

```
------------------------
| user_id | friends_id |
------------------------
|    1    |   many     |
------------------------
```

- If any user have friends more than 1, i must write word 'many'.
- If any user have 1 friend, i must write his ID.

How i can do that?
I googled and can't explain to google my problem.

Comment: GROUP BY, CASE around COUNT in the select list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` to count number of friends. Use a `CASE` to return 'Many' if more than 1 friend, or the friend_id if only one (need to `CAST` to a character type, compatible with 'Many'.)

```
select user_id, 
       case when count(friends_id) > 1 then 'Many'
       else cast(min(friends_id) as varchar(11)) end as friends_id
from friends
group by user_id
```

Comment: What would be if in table `friends` column `friends_id` will be `friends_name` and will be **varchar**? Will _count_ work?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, but the CAST may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I update the query and include

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2406/8)

```
WITH fCount as (
      SELECT user_id, min(friends_id) friends_id, count(friends_id) nFriend
      FROM friends
      GROUP BY user_id
)
select user_id, CASE 
                    WHEN nFriend > 1 THEN 'many'
                    ELSE cast(friends_id as nvarchar(10))
                END friends_id 
from fCount
```

Comment: If you add a GROUP BY, it will be more general and can get data for several user_id's.

Comment: @jarth I update the query. I left the `where user_id = 1` so you can see the result when `count = 1`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select user_id, CASE 
                    WHEN count(friends_id) > 1 THEN 'many'
                    ELSE friends_id
                END friends_id 
from friends 
where user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use below query:

```
                CREATE TABLE #Temp (
                ID INT Identity(1, 1)
                ,UID INT
                ,f_id NVARCHAR(10)
                )

            INSERT INTO #temp
            SELECT 1
                ,2

            UNION ALL

            SELECT 1
                ,3

            UNION ALL

            SELECT 1
                ,4

            UNION ALL

            SELECT 2
                ,1

            SELECT uid
                ,COUNT(f_id) AS COUNT_of_Friends
            INTO #Temp2
            FROM #temp
            GROUP BY Uid

            SELECT t1.Uid
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN t2.COUNT_of_Friends > 1
                        THEN 'Many'
                    ELSE f_id
                    END AS F_id
            FROM #temp T1
            INNER JOIN #Temp2 T2 ON T1.Uid = t2.Uid
```